# Is it possible to play imm4-codec videos?

Tags: video, video-player, medibuntu, w64codecs

Is it possible to watch imm4 codec encoded videos in Ubuntu?

Comment: what version of ubuntu?

Comment: can be 10.04 or later

Comment: Accepted Answer below works for Ubuntu 32bit only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imm4 codec is a restricted codec - covered by patents, so for some countries you should check if you are covered to run this decoder.

*note I've tested this on 11.10*

Install the restricted Medibuntu repository:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Now install mplayer and w32codecs

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer w32codecs
```

Now the important part - mplayer is coded to look for the windows DLL VCMIMM4.dll, however, medibuntu installs a lowercase version that mplayer would not recognised out-of-the-box.  Thus to fix this, create a VCMIMM4.dll file in the codecs folder.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/codecs/vcmimm4.dll /usr/lib/codecs/VCMIMM4.dll
```

Now play your video - e.g.

```
mplayer http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/IMM4/200707170736151.avi
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work on a 64bit install or only 32bit?

Comment: I've only tested this on 32bit.  I think there is "w64codecs" package - give it a try if you have 64bit ubuntu.

Comment: I can confrim that fossfreedom solution it works on 32bit. It does NOT on 64 bit because w64codecs only contains a handful of realplayer codecs and does not fully replace w32codecs. If you need to play a format only supported by w32codecs, you will need to install w32codecs to /usr/lib32 and use a 32-bit version of mplayer (or an alternate method for running 32-bit apps, such as a chroot or virtualbox) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMD64